# How do I install smbmount?

Tags: samba

It seems that `smbmount` is not available in Kubuntu 12.10:

```
 - neptune():~$ smbmount //192.168.0.100/ samba/ -o rw
smbmount: command not found
 - neptune():~$ apt-file search smbmount
manpages-zh: /usr/share/man/zh_CN/man8/smbmount.8.gz
manpages-zh: /usr/share/man/zh_TW/man8/smbmount.8.gz
 - neptune():~$ aptitude search smbmount
 - neptune():~$
```

Furthermore, I cannot seem to use `smbfs` to mount:

```
 - neptune():~$ sudo mount -t smbfs //192.168.0.100/ samba/ -o rw
mount: unknown filesystem type 'smbfs'
 - neptune():~$ aptitude search smbfs
 - neptune():~$
```

Any ideas how to continue?

Comment: Lamentably, the Debian samba package installs a "man samba" page that still talks about smbmount instead of mount.cifs - thanks for the more up-to-date information !

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`smbmount` has been deprecated in favor of `mount.cifs`. I want to say "since at least 2008" but I can't find a reference.

Here's the accompanying [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/smbmount.8.html). You would use these parameters instead:

```
 sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.0.100/ samba/ -o rw
```

You might also need to install the [cifs-utils [image: Install cifs-utils]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cifs-utils) package.

......

Comment: The package name is [cifs-utils](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cifs-utils/). Thanks anyway

Comment: For the record, this is what worked for me on Debian 8: `mount.cifs //{ip address}/{dir} /mnt/remote --verbose -o "port=8888,username=foo,password=bar,sec=ntlm"`.

Comment: Building off of @AdrianoP I had to add a "vers=1.0" to the end: 

`mount.cifs //{ip address}/{dir} /mnt/remote --verbose -o "port=8888,username=foo,password=bar,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0"`

Comment: I also had to install `keyutils` for sec=krb support or I would get an error 2 when trying to mount

Comment: The `-o rw` which I consider the important part gives me `mount: bad usage \\ Try 'mount --help' for more information.`

Comment: All I had to do was specify a username on the Samba server and 3.0 as the version to connect succesfully. i.e. `mount -t cifs -o username=brian,vers=3.0 //ip_address/directory loc_of_mountpoint`