# How to process output from smbclient

Tags: command-line, samba, smb

I connected to a Windows share using `smbclient`. In smbclient shell I can't pass an argument (`ls -lh`)! I can't place a pipe (`ls | grep 4547`)! I can't even redirect output to a file like in a basic **shell** (`ls > ls.txt`)!

How is it supposed to use?! I'm terrified by it's uselessness and futility!

Please give me any examples of `smbclient` usage that stand for `grep`'ing things or redirecting output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand `smbclient` shell does not support `grep` and **io redirection**. But you can just mount your samba share to local file system and use all *features* of bash shell.

You need to install [cifs-utils](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cifs-utils).

```
$ sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Now you should be able to mount samba share. Here is example

```
$ mount.cifs //192.168.1.1/share_point /path_to_your/local/folder -o user,uid=1000,rw,workgroup=DEV,credentials=/path_to_credentials/.cifs
```

You have to create `/path_to_your/local/folder`

```
$ mkdir /mnt/my_share
```

and credentials file. I suggest to create folder `crd` in your `$HOME`, change permission to `700`.

```
$ mkdir ~/crd
$ chmod 700 ~/crd
```

Now in `$HOME/crd` create `.cifs` file with this content:

```
username=value
password=value
domain=value
```

Change permission to this file to `600`.

```
$ chmod 600 ~/crd/.cifs
```

Now you only need to substitute IP address:

```
$ mount.cifs //192.168.1.1/share_point /mnt/my_share -o user,uid=1000,rw,workgroup=DEV,credentials=$HOME/.cifs
```

---

You may also want this mount to be mounted on boot automatically. Add this to your `/etc/fstab`, at the end

```
//192.168.1.1/share /mnt/my_share cifs uid=1000,credentials=$HOME/.cifs,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,noauto,user 0 0
```

Don't forget to substitute $HOME with your home folder, and IP address with appropriate IP.

---

Sources

1. [mount.cifs man](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/mount.cifs.8.html)
2. [About smbmount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/232998/how-do-i-install-smbmount)
3. [About fstab and smb mount](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477236/mounting-a-remote-folder-using-cifs)